# Error while reading source file name starts with a number in informatica

Tags: informatica-powercenter, informatica

The source file name in my project starts with a number for example `20070908abcd.csv`. Informatica is not allowing to read the source in the designer and displays the following message:

```
The first character in this name cannot be a number.
```

Could you please let me know how to handle as many source files are of this format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of a source file can start with a digit and it will be processed correctly. However, the first character in the name of a source transformation cannot be a number.

When importing a file, enter a correct name (by default, file name is used) for the new source that will be created:

[image: Flat File Import Wizard - PowerCenter]

Comment: As a thumb rule, if a file can exist on the file system with a given name, it can be read by informatica as such.  The rules are for informatica objects only, not outside.